# Will Azure SP2013 server work for public sites?

Tags: 2013, online, server

I know SP2013 Online will not work for public sites - I work for education with many public sites in our SP farm. But if we wanted to go online and not be on-prem anymore, would it work with a Azure server loaded with SP2013 or 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but that's just running SharePoint On-Prem in Azure IaaS (VMs). Fairly expensive on a month-to-month basis, but certainly supported.

Comment: And we would still be able to host the public sites that way? Arguably, it would be cheaper going on-prem, but the powers at-be are wanting a redundant solution as we just went through a hurricane and had damage done to our NOC.....

Comment: Yes, you'd still be able to host public sites as you're running SharePoint On-Prem, just happens to be on a different virtualization platform.